# How to use contents of DataRow?

Tags: .net, casting, polymorphism, tostring, datarow

If a `DataRow` has been generated by using a `DbCommand` and `DbDataAdapter`, how do you access the contents of a single value in the `DataRow`?

If I know that `DataRow("MyField")` will contain a `String`, how do I get the `String` out of this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is known that the data type of the field is a `String`, then it can simply be assigned to a `String` variable:

```
Dim strMyField As String = row("MyField")
```

An exception may be raised if the data type of the field is not in fact a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it casting to string you looking for?

```
      DataRow("MyField") as string
```

Comment: Since you asked for string i suggested use "as", it will work with all reference types, but for value type best practice to check null. Perhaps you can use datarow.isnull property which also works same.

Answer (score 0):

You need just cast to `String` object

```
DataRow dr = .....//retrive the DataRow object
String yourString = (String)dr["MyField"];
//or if you use System.Linq;
String yourString = dr.Field<String>("MyField");
```